# Using HttpsURLConnection on Google App Engine to retrieve certificate details

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ssl

I'm working on a Java app - to be run on App Engine - which routinely checks the SSL certificates used by our web apps and gives us a warning if they're about to expire.

I was hoping to use the following code, which throws an exception if the certificate expires in less than 2 weeks (I've simplified it a little by removing some error checking).

```
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 14);
Date twoWeeksInTheFuture = cal.getTime();

URL url = new URL(https_url);
HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

// Need the following line in order to establish a connection with the server
con.getResponseCode();

Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
Certificate certificate = certs[0];
X509Certificate x509Certificate = (X509Certificate) certificate;
x509Certificate.checkValidity(twoWeeksInTheFuture);
```

That code works fine outside of App Engine (e.g. in the main method of a Java class). However, when run in App Engine the following exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.apphosting.utils.security.urlfetch.URLFetchServiceStreamHandler$Connection cannot be cast to javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection
    at com.bronzelabs.httpschecker.servlets.cron.HttpsChecker.doGet(HttpsChecker.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
```

HttpsURLConnection is in the [whitelist of allowed classes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist) so there must be a way to use this class on App Engine (well, you'd assume). It just seems like you can't use URL.openConnection().

Does anyone know of a way to establish an HTTPS Connection (using Java on App Engine) and view details on the SSL certificates?

Note: I've looked at Google's URLFetchService. There doesn't appear to be any way to access the certificates (only the contents of the HTTP request).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how much that information helps, but I thought you might like some confirmation with respect to your hypothesis. :)

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to do this with the built-in URLFetchService in the Standard Environment, as you've (correctly) observed. For details about what you *can* do with URLFetchService and HTTPS, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/issue-requests). You may be able use a third-party library to do this, but [request proxying](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/outbound-requests#request_proxying) could also prove a roadblock (try the [sockets API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/), maybe?); you could try using the [flexible environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/) instead depending on your use case.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I think the flexible environment will be the only way. The standard environment was attractive as the service wouldn't get used a great deal so it would easily fit inside the free tier. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! I'm sorry I don't have a more satisfying answer for you. If cost is your foremost concern, you could use App Engine Cron in the Standard Environment to call some code of yours which [calls a Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/). The function would have to be written in Node.js but it would be free (at least for now).

Comment: That's clever. I hadn't thought of using Cloud Functions. I'll give that a try. I was just being a bit of a cheapskate so using the standard environment isn't a big deal.